# 2 decimal places instead of one, but code is not requiring a float

Tags: python, codio

I'm trying to understand how to get 2 decimal places in this code. Codio is reading it as one. It is not requiring a float command. If I were to enter a float, where would I actually add the  $%.2f command in regard to this string. I am very new to coding, so I just want to make sure that I am creating the proper syntax. Been working on this for hours.

```
if rentalCode == "B":
    budgetCharge = 40.00
    baseCharge = rentalPeriod * budgetCharge

elif rentalCode == "D":
   budgetCharge = 60.00
   baseCharge = rentalPeriod * budgetCharge

elif rentalCode == "W":
   budgetCharge = 190.00
   baseCharge = rentalPeriod * budgetCharge

print(baseCharge)
```

Comment: I hope you're referring to the documentation for the correct version? 
In py2.x the print formatting was different which has changed In py3.x along with other syntax as well.

Answer (score 1):

Defining `budgetCharge` with 2 decimal places will have no use. You can specify how many decimal places by using format strings:

```
# old style
print('%.2f' % baseCharge)

# new style
print('{:.2f}'.format(baseCharge))
```